# How to get an old release of a spacy model?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, nlp, spacy

I manage to install an old version of spacy with `pip3 install spacy==2.2.4`.

However, when I follow this up with
`python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`, it downloads `en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 9):

spaCy `2.2.4` is compatible with `en_core_web_sm` `2.2.5` and `2.2.0`

You can install it directly like so:

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

Check [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/blob/master/compatibility.json) for model compatibility:

```
"2.2.4": {
    "en_vectors_web_lg": ["2.1.0"],
    "en_core_web_sm": ["2.2.5", "2.2.0"],
    "en_core_web_md": ["2.2.5", "2.2.0"],
    "en_core_web_lg": ["2.2.5", "2.2.0"]
    }
```

Comment: This throws the following error for me:   ERROR: Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-unpack-vwn2rhmj/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0 (downloaded from /tmp/pip-req-build-i4l4lu6m, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-req-build-i4l4lu6m

Comment: https://spacy.io/usage/models#download  This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can check whether language models that you have downloaded are compatible with the currently installed version of spaCy by running `validate` command. The command is also useful to detect out-of-sync model links. Check [here](https://spacy.io/api/cli)

```
python3 -m spacy validate
```

After running this command, if you get check marks for every model you have downloaded then this means everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Spacy requires you to have matching spacy builds with spacy models.  If you are forced to use a older spacy build, say 3.0.x instead of the latest 3.2.x, you will need to install the older model.

Inorder to install, you can use the command (for 3.0 en_core_web_sm model)

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-3.0.0 --direct
```

Comment: python -m is used to run a program that is created by you. To install Spacy, I tried in Linux Ubuntu:

sudo pip install  spacy==2.3.7 .... 

pip is the general install program for Python, if you don't have this then install that first. sudo is needed since you add this to the root directories.